# New Post bubble

Tags: posts

How can I add a bubble that says "new content" to all posts within the last week?  I have looked at all available solutions but they only appear to be for menu items.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>
<div class="bubble"><?php _e('NEW', 'mytheme_name'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the above one will show NEW div for each post posted in 24 hours. You can simply add anywhere in your posts loop.

You can use `7 * 24 * 60 * 60` to make it weekly. More info about php time is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).